# Color themes are strange/incorrect in terminal emulator

Tags: emacs, terminal, konsole

I'm running emacs-nox 23.3 in Konsole (from kde) emulator, the most color themes have strange colors.

For example, i like the [Solarized Theme](https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/). I expect the theme should look like this:

[image: Solarized Theme]
<sub>(source: [ethanschoonover.com](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/img/screen-ruby-dark.png))</sub>

However, this is what I get:

[Broken Solarized Theme http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/3881/voronoi2.png](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/3881/voronoi2.png)

Most of themes that comes in emacs-color-theme package have similar behavior. I tried to change the Konsole color settings - no result. I also tried to replace my .Xresources with [this one](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/c350650cb74eed91895272d4b9d0fde8a335d223/xresources-colors-solarized), with no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need 256 colors in your terminal for most color themes to have decent appearance. Try adding this to your .bashrc (or .zshrc):

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

After you've sourced the setting (`source .bashrc`), start again emacs and hopefully the themes will be looking much better.

Comment: I put this line into .Xresources and i wondering why it is not working. -.- ty!

Answer (score 5):

No, do not put this line

> TERM=xterm-256color

to .Xresources. Try to run emacs with this command:

> TERM=xterm-256color emacs

and if everything is ok, put this line to your .bashrc or .bash_profile file:

> alias emacs='TERM=xterm-256color emacs'

After that your can execute emacs with usual 'emacs' cmd and get the normal colors in editor.